# Add custom field on OpenCart 2.1.0.1. checkout page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have created a custom payment method in my OpenCart 2.1.0.1. I have edited my `payment_method.tpl` as well and added a custom field for customers to add one identifical number which is exactly 10 symbols lenght. This is my HTML:

```
<label class="control-label" for="input-payment-egn"><?php echo $text_egn; ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="egn" value="" placeholder="Въведете вашето ЕГН" id="input-payment-egn"
               class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

How can I require this field, validate it and to add it in order info in admin page and in clients order info?

Answer (score 1):

So you hard-coded for an extra field? 
Why don't you use the opencart's functionality for extra fields? You can make it required and you can place it wherever you want. Account or Checkout. You can have validation rules and/or change the type of the field.

[image]

Edited my answer for the javascript & the HTML that will check if the field has value or not and also accept only 10 chars:

The html code should change to:

```html
<label class="control-label" for="input-payment-egn"><?php echo $text_egn; ?></label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="egn" value="" placeholder="Въведете вашето ЕГН" id="input-payment-egn" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

```js
/* With 'form' it will fire on any form into the page. Please change it, by form's id. */
$('form').on('submit', function() { 
  /* Get the value and the length of the field */
  var egn = $('#input-payment-egn').val();
  var egnLength = egn.length;
  
  /* If it's less than 10 never continue */
  if (egnLength < 10) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Because this field is just for my custom payment method ( this is specific identical number, so i must collect it from the buyer ONLY if he choose this payment method, otherwise i dont need it)

Comment: So, then the file you edited, shouldn't be edited. Every payment method has it's own .tpl file (for oc 1.5.x - 2.3.x) into catalog/view/payment/{payment method} / folder. There you can create all the fields you want and add a javascript to check if the field has value, then continue, else don't. The javascript should fire on form.submit and if the value is not there should cancel the submit.

Comment: Yes! That javascript is what im searching for! I edited my .tpl file of my own custom payment method!  I think you understood me now :)

Comment: I updated my 1st answer above, with an example. Hope this help you more.

Comment: You will need to add a span with the message into your html code and call it to be visible, before the "return false" js code.